# Inserting HTML to close and open divs in WP_Query loops

Tags: wp-query, categories, conditional-tags

The output I am trying to achieve is this:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="small-1 large-4 columns"><a href="some link"><img src="some image"></a></div>
<div class="small-1 large-4 columns"><a href="some link"><img src="some image"></a></div>
<div class="small-1 large-4 columns"><a href="some link"><img src="some image"></a></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="small-1 large-4 columns"><a href="some link"><img src="some image"></a></div>
<div class="small-1 large-4 columns"><a href="some link"><img src="some image"></a></div>
<div class="small-1 large-4 columns"><a href="some link"><img src="some image"></a></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="small-1 large-4 columns"><a href="some link"><img src="some image"></a></div>
<div class="small-1 large-4 columns"><a href="some link"><img src="some image"></a></div>
<div class="small-1 large-4 columns"><a href="some link"><img src="some image"></a></div>
</div>
```

This is my PHP

```
<?php $first_query = new WP_Query('cat=22&posts_per_page=9'); ?>

<?php while ($first_query->have_posts()) : $first_query->the_post(); ?>

<?php if($first_query->current_post && !($first_query->current_post % 3) ) : ?>
<div class="row">

<?php endif; ?> 

<?php if($first_query->current_post && !($first_query->current_post % 1) ) : ?>  

    <div class="small-1 large-4 columns"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">    <?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?></a></div>

 <?php endif; ?>   

  <?php if($first_query->current_post && !($first_query->current_post % 3) ) : ?>

</div>

<?php endif; ?> 

<?php endwhile; // End the loop.  ?>
```

So basically I need a DIV with the class of row to enclose three divs with the class of small-1 large-4 columns. What I'm getting with the code shown in this post is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simplify things by using the [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) PHP function, to split an array into smaller chunks. Then you don't need to worry about opening and closing divs with some math tricks.

Let's rewrite your code snippet and hopefully make it easier to work with:

```
// Let's get all posts with thumbnail set in some category
$args = [ 
    'cat'            => 22,
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'meta_key'       => '_thumbnail_id'
];

// Fetch posts
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $query->have_posts() )
{
    while ( $query->have_posts() )
    {
        $query->the_post(); 

        // Collect all items into a temp array    
        $tmp[] = sprintf( 
            '<div class="small-1 large-4 columns"><a href="%s">%s</a></div>',
            get_permalink(),
            get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), 'large' )
        );
    } 

    // Split the divs into rows of 3 items
    $rows = array_chunk( $tmp, 3 );

    // Housecleaning
    unset( $tmp );
    wp_reset_postdata();

    // Output the rows
    foreach( $rows as $row )
        printf( '<div class="row">%s</div>', join( '', $row ) ); 

}
```

*Look Ma, no math used here! ;-)*

Hopefully you can adjust this to your needs.

Comment: *Look Ma, no math used here! ;-)* ...... *and I'm able to keep all my teeth*. Great alternative solution to using counters ;-)

Comment: we could use a  good dental smile here    @PieterGoosen

Comment: This has been tremendously helpful! Thank you very much. I do have one more question to add to this. I need to create a "view more" link to view the next 9 articles. I would want them to load the same way (max of 9 articles per page)

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. There are [*pagination*](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) parameters available in `WP_Query` that you should check out further, regarding the "view more" feature. @C.Ruben

Answer (score 2):

For the maths version ;) -

Open and close the first/last row *outside* the loop, then you only have to worry about closing/opening rows every third post that isn't the last post.

```
echo '<div class="row">';

while ( $query->have_posts() ){

    // output content for this post here

    if( 0 == ( $first_query->current_post + 1 ) % 3
        && ( $first_query->current_post + 1 ) != $first_query->post_count ){
            echo '</div><div class="row">';
    }

}

echo '</div>';
```

Comment: *For the maths version ;) ... which might have one loosing a shiny ivory or two* ;-)